# Can't retrieve data in table from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to load data into table using JQuery and AJAX but when I click on the button data is not retrieved. I have done coding as shown below:

```
var globalgrid;
```

Here I am going to call json url and try to display it in the table.

```
function loadgrid() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'http://instatalk.in/sip/GetApprovedUsersList?page=1&limit=10',
        success: function(griddata) {
            globalgrid = griddata.lines;

            // remove all data - but the headers!
            $("#gridtable").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();

            if (globalgrid.length === 0) {
                $('#errormsg').html('Sorry, <strong>no</strong> rows returned!');
                return;
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < globalgrid.length; i++) {
                var line = globalgrid[i];
                // insert after last row!
                $('#gridtable > tbody:last').append('<tr><td>' + line.Id + '</td><td>' + line.AccountId + '</td><td>' + line.Name + '</td><td>' + line.IsFranchiseUser + '</td></tr>');
            }
        },
        error: function(data, errorText) {
            $("#errormsg").html(errorText).show();
        }
    });
}
```

I am getting the table heading only. When I click on the button I want data to be retrieved from the json data. I don't know where I am going wrong. Please do help.

This is my json file:

```
{"results":[{"Id":17,"AccountId":"5737329468","Name":"Martin (Nigeria)","IsFranchiseUser":false},{"Id"
:16,"AccountId":"3644824444","Name":"Deep Patel","IsFranchiseUser":false},{"Id":15,"AccountId":"4692068407"
,"Name":"Jacob (kiribati)","IsFranchiseUser":false},{"Id":14,"AccountId":"4650982975","Name":"sebin John
 (spain)","IsFranchiseUser":false},{"Id":13,"AccountId":"2855375107","Name":"Jassi want(new jersey)"
,"IsFranchiseUser":false},{"Id":12,"AccountId":"6242007588","Name":"Moussa","IsFranchiseUser":false}
,{"Id":11,"AccountId":"3075258818","Name":"srkrbm (saudi arab)","IsFranchiseUser":true},{"Id":10,"AccountId"
:"3615509810","Name":"Om Saini","IsFranchiseUser":false},{"Id":9,"AccountId":"9251133143","Name":"swati
 mohandas","IsFranchiseUser":false},{"Id":8,"AccountId":"8143395019","Name":"babu Kuppu","IsFranchiseUser"
:false}],"totalAccounts":16}
```

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle so we can see the results?

Comment: What does it show if you console.log griddata in the success handler? Are you in fact watching the JavaScript console as this all happens?

Comment: how is the click event on the button set up to invoke the loadgrid function

Comment: I am new to this so I don't have much idea on what to do and how to do it. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I gave the click event as as <button onclick="loadgrid();">Load grid data</button>

Comment: Itaws, in your browser, there are "Developer Tools". Google should tell you how to enable (if using Safari) and then open the JavaScript console. Now in your code, as the first part of your success function, add `console.log(griddata)` and see what it shows you. It might in fact be the server-side that's not returning all the data you're expecting.

Comment: link you've provided `http://instatalk.in/sip/GetApprovedUsersList?page=1&limit=10` is not working. It says, `Error 404`.

Comment: Where should I add console.log(griddata)?

Comment: Right inside your success handler, as I mentioned. ;) `success: function(griddata){ console.log(griddata); //then the rest }` Looks from your screenshot like you're probably getting proper JSON. But the screenshot doesn't zoom (for me?) and copy-pastable data would be better. The copy-pastable version would be found in the "Response" tab of the same area you took a screenshot from.

Comment: I have copy-pasted the json data. I also added console.log(griddata) but it does not give any result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line: globalgrid = griddata.lines;

According to your Json data format, you should use griddata.results.

Comment: I made the change. In the console it is giving error $ is not defined.

Comment: You are not including jQuery properly, or you are using a closure and not passing jQuery into it. Or the $ is conflicting. If you think you have jQuery included, just change to `jQuery.ajax(...)` and see if it works.

Comment: When I replace $.ajax with jQuery.ajax I get the error "ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined"